# How can I get the color options for VS.Php working?

Tags: php, visual-studio, colors, visual-studio-2008

Recently I installed a Visual Studio 2008 extension called VS.Php, made by Jcx Software: http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php

It looks brilliant; IntelliSense and debugging for PHP! A godsend!

Unfortunately, it assumes I have a white background in Visual Studio, but I have the hacker style "black terminal with green text", which makes some of the elements blend in with the background.

Now, this should be in the Fonts/Colors options, but the elements do not show up.

The website says the following:

> If you are not seen the php entries you need run the Visual Studio package registration under this user. Open the Visual Studio command line and type:
>
> devenv /setup

But when I run that, I get:

```
\>devenv /setup
Command "devenv" is not valid.
```

How can I get the color options to show up?

Comment: >>I have the hacker style "black terminal with green text"<< Isn't there a law against this? E.g. the "protect innocent bystanders from eye cancer" law? ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK: It's so people in the train go "Oh what's he doing? Hmmm a black screen with green text? He must be one of those 'hackers' I've heard about. Better not bother him before he blows up my e-mail".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [devenv executable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(VS.80).aspx) is located in the Common7\IDE directory of your visual studio installation.

Comment: That was it. :D

I was using the built-in command line (Ctrl+Alt+A) while I should have been using the external command line. All the color options now show up.